# iTextSharp: Setting text on textfield that is on a table cell results in text being too wide and squashed

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I think this might be a bug, but if anyone can help I'd appreciate it. I currently have another question open that deals with a similar issue, but I think this question better exemplifies the problem, and more simply too. That being said I don't want to delete the old one in case it increases my wait time. I yield to the mods to decide which question is better.

Here's a sample application that creates a pdf, then a table. It adds a cell to the table and then ties a fieldpositioningevent to the cell event.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace iTextSharpTextBoxInTableCell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a PDF with a TextBox in a table cell
            BaseFont bfHelvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, false);
            Font helvetica12 = new Font(bfHelvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 18f, 18f, 18f, 18f);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("TextBoxInTableCell.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

            doc.Open();
            PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(1);
            myTable.TotalWidth = 568f;
            myTable.LockedWidth = true;
            myTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

            TextField tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(67, 585, 140, 800), "cellTextBox");
            tf.Text = "test";
            PdfPCell tbCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", helvetica12));
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents events =
                new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, tf.GetTextField());
            tbCell.CellEvent = events;

            myTable.AddCell(tbCell);

            doc.Add(myTable);

            doc.Close();

            fs.Close();
            Process.Start("TextBoxInTableCell.pdf");
            Console.WriteLine("End Of Program Execution");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what this field looks like when it's generated: [image: squashed]

As you can see, the text is squashed. I've published the generated pdf [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrj0qtbcepefgag/TextBoxInTableCell.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm definitely seeing what you're seeing and as @mkl said in your other post, the problem comes down to the appearance's `BBOX` entry not being set to the same size as the field. I can't really find too many examples of `FieldPositioningEvents` in the wild and the ones that do exist appear to be copy-and-paste's of each other for the most part.

Anyway, if you read the actual code for [`FieldPositioningEvents`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/events/FieldPositioningEvents.cs) you'll see that it can be used for both page events as well as cell events which makes me think it was intended for broader purposes possibly, but that's just a guess on my part.

One solution is to just write your own subclass of `IPdfPCellEvent`. Below is an example of that that follows the example provided by `FieldPositioningEvents` however it is specific to `TextFields` since we're interested in setting the `/BBOX` entry. It has two constructors, one that works very similar to `FieldPositioningEvents` that takes a `PdfWriter` and a `TextField` and one that just takes the most commonly set properties of a `TextFields` and actually creates it for you. The `CellLayout` is part of the interface contract and actually figures out where the annotation should be drawn.

```
public class SingleCellFieldPositioningEvent : IPdfPCellEvent {

    public TextField Field { get; set; }
    public PdfWriter Writer { get; set; }
    public float Padding { get; set; }

    public SingleCellFieldPositioningEvent(PdfWriter writer, TextField field) {
        this.Field = field;
        this.Writer = writer;
    }

    public SingleCellFieldPositioningEvent(PdfWriter writer, string fieldName, string text = "", BaseFont font = null, float fontSize = 14 ) {
        //The rectangle gets changed later so it doesn't matter what we use
        var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1, 1);

        //Create the field and set various properties
        this.Field = new TextField(writer, rect, fieldName);
        this.Field.Text = text;
        if (null == font) {
            font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        }
        this.Field.Font = font;
        this.Field.FontSize = fontSize;

        this.Writer = writer;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        //Create the field's rectangle based on the current cell and requested padded
        var newRect = new PdfRectangle(rect.GetLeft(Padding), rect.GetBottom(Padding), rect.GetRight(Padding), rect.GetTop(Padding));

        //Set the appearance's rectangle to the same as the box
        Field.Box = newRect.Rectangle;

        //Get the raw field
        var tf = this.Field.GetTextField();

        //Change the field's rectangle
        tf.Put(PdfName.RECT, newRect);

        //Add the annotation to the writer
        Writer.AddAnnotation(tf);
    }
}
```

You can use this in two different ways. Either manually create a field and set various properties:

```
//The rectangle is actually changed in the cell event so it doesn't matter what we use
TextField tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1, 1), "cellTextBox");
tf.Text = "test";
tf.Font = bfHelvetica;
tf.FontSize = 14;
PdfPCell tbCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", helvetica12));
tbCell.CellEvent = new SingleCellFieldPositioningEvent(writer, tf);
```

Or just pass the properties in:

```
PdfPCell tbCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", helvetica12));
tbCell.CellEvent = new SingleCellFieldPositioningEvent(writer, "cellTextBox", "test", bfHelvetica, 14);
myTable.AddCell(tbCell);
```

Comment: Spectacular answer. I almost hope they'll incorporate this into the code though it is, admittedly, somewhat uncommon. Thanks!

Comment: I'm only specifically handling the `/BBox` value, there actually might be several other appearance states that might need to be set. If you run into those let me know.